# Where should JUnit specific Guice module be configured?

Tags: eclipse, junit, dependency-injection, guice, eclipse-plugin

I'm going to start using dependency injection in my Eclipse plugin. My test plugin depends on the main one and should use different injection context. Production should work fine standalone (it should have its own injection context), but behave differently when used from tests (should use Junit's injection context).

How could I resolve the injector so that a different one is used in production and in tests?

I don't like the idea to somehow inject context manually in a static variable on test start. Is there a better way? Can extensions be somehow used for that?

I know that in e4 there is a solution for that, but I'm bound to Eclipse Indigo for now and could not find quickly how exactly is that done in latest version. A link to injector configuration with an ability to override in test infrastructure in e4 source is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, this question just comes down to: How to inject injector? :)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up writing my own JUnit runner modeled largely after the Spring JUnit runner, but would highly recommend looking at the [Jukito project](https://github.com/ArcBees/Jukito) now.

At this point I try to have one Guice module per feature, so I end up with one Guice module for test that installs the production module and overrides or binds any external dependencies. I keep that test module in a base test class along with the necessary annotation for the JUnit runner, which is very similar to the JukitoModule examples in the link above.